# Prolog Insult/Seating problem

Tags: list, prolog

This is the problem.
"Mr. and Mrs. Astor, Mr. and Mrs. Blake, Mr. and Mrs. Crane, and Mrs. and Mrs. Davis were seated around a circular table. Mrs. Astor was insulted by Mr. Blake, who sat next to her on her left. Mr. Blake was insulted by Mrs. Crane, who sat opposite him accross the center of the table. Mrs. Crane was insulted by the hostess, Mrs. Davis. The hostess was the only person to sit between each of a married couple.  The hostess was the only person to sit between each of a married couple. The hostess was insulted by the only person to sit between two men. Who insulted the hostess? Also print the seating order starting with the hostess."

So what I tried was

```
insult(A, B). /*A insults B*/

seats([seat(_,1),seat(_,2),seat(_,3),seat(_,4),
seat(_,5),seat(_,6),seat(_,7),seat(_,8)]). /*Clockwise*/

table(Seats,Who) :- seats(Seats),
    member(seat(mrastor,MA),Seats), 
    member(seat(mrsastor,MRSA),Seats),
    member(seat(mrblake,MB),Seats), insult(MB,MRSA), MB=:=MRSA+1,
    member(seat(mrsblake,MRSB),Seats),
    member(seat(mrcrane,MC),Seats), insult(MRSC,MB),
    member(seat(mrscrane,MRSC),Seats), opposite(MRSC, MB),
    member(seat(mrdavis,MD),Seats), 
    member(seat(mrsdavis,MRSD),Seats), insult(MRSD,MRSC),
    (between_men(MA, Who, MB); between_men(MA, Who, MC); 
    between_men(MA, Who, MD); between_men(MB, Who, MC); 
    between_men(MB, Who, MD); between_men(MC, Who, MD)),


    print_seat(Seats), print_who(Who, mrsdavis). /*insult(Who, mrsdavis).*/

print_seat([A | B]) :- write(A), nl,  print_seat(B).
print_seat([]).

print_who(Who, what) :- insult(Who, mrsdavis), write(Who).

member(X, [X | _]).
member(X, [_ | Y]) :- member(X, Y).

adjacent(X, Y) :- X =:= Y+1.
adjacent(X, Y) :- X =:= Y-1.

opposite(X, Y) :- X =:= Y+4. 
opposite(X, Y) :- X =:= Y-4.

between_men(X, Y, Z) :- X=Y+1, Y=Z+1.
between_men(X, Y, Z) :- X=Y-1, Y=Z-1.
```

I'm totally new in Prolog and this problem I'm not sure if I'm coding in the right way. Any suggestions?

I really don't understand what the phrase "The hostess was the only person to sit between each of a married couple." Is Mr. Davis also a Hostess?  And the hostess other than the two couple that sit next to the hostess, all the other couples sit next to their partners? Kind of confusing...

Comment: host*ess* would be a woman, and "between each of a married couple" would mean the insulter of the hostess sat between a husband and wife. I don't see anything that implies partners necessarily sitting next to each other.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx Ok That's a great hint! Thanks :D

Answer (score -1):

You can find similar problems and solutions in the "examples" folder of the current Logtalk distribution. You can also browse the source code on-line here:

https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/puzzles

See, for example, the "houses.lgt" (a classical) or the "camp_swampy.lgt" source files.

Comment: link is dead..can you find a new one?

Comment: Fixed outdated link.